# Hyperlink on angular material button does not cause browser to jump to that link

Tags: html, angularjs, button, angular-material

I am using angular material on angularjs v1.

I am having problems with a simple menu bar using angular material. Here is the html code for the menu bar;

```
<md-toolbar layout="row" class="md-whiteframe-z3" style="padding: 0px;margin:0px;float: left;">
    <h2>Test page</h2>
    <md-button href="Data1.html">Data1</md-button>
    <md-button href="Data2.html">Data2</md-button>
</md-toolbar>
```

[image]

When I click on `Data1` button, the browser URL changes to "http://127.0.0.1/test-site/webroot/app/Data1.html" but the browser does not go to that webpage. I have to manually refresh the page to force the browser to go to that webpage.

How can I get the browser to go to that page when the button is pressed?

EDIT: The existing answer works but it opens a new tab. I would like the browser to go to the new webpage on the existing tab. Preferably, it would be nice if the solution can be purely in html but using javascript would be fine. I have created a bounty.

Comment: What's the console output when you click on the button ?

Comment: @Manish Singh, nothing at the moment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `ng-href` like this

```
<div>
 <md-button ng-href="{{googleUrl}}" target="_blank">Go to Google</md-button>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/gDzYHXZcnGkzrh7C7E80?p=preview)**

**UPDATE:**

You can achieve it by mentioning target="_self"

```
   <md-button ng-href="{{googleUrl}}" target="_self">Go to Google</md-button>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/sOupTd2358SfY73jXJGF?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. It almost works. The problem is that the Chrome browser will open a new tab. I would like to chrome browser to move to the new page on the same tab.

Comment: you mean replace the existing page?

Comment: Yes, I mean replacing the existing page. Thank you.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/rj5AAN8KWP7Fhect2u4a check this demo, you need to download and run.

Comment: Sajeetharan, thanks for helping.  My preference would be to have a solution solely in html without using javascript. It looks like an overkill, but thanks a lot.

Comment: do you mind if I wait a little longer for other answers to come? I will mark it as answer if yours is the only or best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `window.location`.

HTML

```
<md-button ng-click="changePage('Data1.html')">Data1</md-button>
<md-button ng-click="changePage('Data2.html')">Data2</md-button>
```

JS

```
$scope.changePage= function(page){
    window.location.assign(window.location.origin + '/test-site/webroot/app/' + page);
}
```

I can't test it, so I'm not sure that there are no bugs : ) But something similar should be what you need. Let me know how it works!

Answer (score 1):

### Angular has `$location` and `ng-href` to help you do that -:

For example when using `ng-href` you can do the following

**1. (link, don't reload)**

```
<a id="link-1" href ng-click="value = 1">link 1</a>
```

**2. (link, don't reload)**

```
<a id="link-2" href="" ng-click="value = 2">link 2</a>
```

**3. (link, reload!)**

```
<a id="link-3" ng-href="/{{'123'}}">link 3</a>
```

**4. (link, don't reload)**

```
<a id="link-4" href="" name="xx" ng-click="value = 4">anchor</a>
```

**5. (no link)**

```
<a id="link-5" name="xxx" ng-click="value = 5">anchor</a>
```

**6. (link, change location)**

```
<a id="link-6" ng-href="{{value}}">link</a>
```

The `$location` service parses the URL in the browser address bar (based on `window.location`) and makes the URL available to your application. Changes to the URL in the address bar are reflected into the `$location` service and changes to $location are reflected into the browser address bar.

So any time your application needs to react to a change in the current URL or if you want to change the current URL in the browser. **

### BUT

It does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed. To reload the page after changing the URL, use the lower-level API, `$window.location.href.`

### READ MORE FROM

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref